# @MockEndpointsAndSkip not resolving dynamic pattern

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I am trying to write unit tests for my Spring Boot with camel routes application. My Producer for the route is a Kafka Endpoint and the URI is defined in the application.properties file. I am trying to mock this Kafka producer endpoint, but it is not resolving the URI value.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@MockEndpointsAndSkip("kafka:${kafka.servers}?*")
public class MyApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;
      ........
      //Some debug code
      // list available endpoints
      camelContext.getEndpoints().forEach((Endpoint endpoint) -> log.info("Endpoint="+endpoint));
      .............
}
```

In the above pseduocode, the kafka.servers value to @MockEndpointsAndSkip annotation is defined in application.properties file as
kafka.servers=localhost:9092

When I print list of endpoints, I see the unresolved value
Endpoint=mock://kafka:$%7Bkafka.servers%7D

I would expect:
Endpoint=mock://kafka:localhost:9092

Is this the wrong way of doing it?

Thanx in advance for any help!!

### Issue with Mock Testing (sorry am a camel newbie)

Here is my Camel routes that I want to unit test using MockEndpoints:

```
from("kafka:{{kafka.servers}}?topic={{kafka.consumer.topic}}&groupId={{kafka.consumer.groupId}}")
    .to("direct:notify");

from("direct:notify")
    .log("direct:notfy");
```

Here is my Test code which is failing the assertion of receiving 1 Exchange. It appears that the Producer is never sending the message to my Kafka Mockendpoint:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@MockEndpointsAndSkip("kafka:{{kafka.servers}}?*|direct:notify")
public class NotificationApplicationTests {     

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext context;

    @Value("${kafka.servers}")
    private String kafkaServers;

    @EndpointInject(uri="mock:kafka:{{kafka.servers}}")
    private MockEndpoint mockKafka;

    @EndpointInject(uri="mock:direct:notify")
    private MockEndpoint mockDirect;

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate notiProducer;

    @Test
    public void testMockEndpoints() throws Exception{                                       

        mockDirect.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
        mockDirect.whenAnyExchangeReceived( (Exchange exchange) -> {
            //NEVER GETS HERE!!
            log.info("MOCK DIRECT exchange received");          
        });     

        String payload = "{'email': 'test@gmail.com', 'data': 'ABC1234'}";

        notiProducer.sendBody(mockKafka, payload);

        mockDirect.assertIsSatisfied();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Camel's property placeholders syntax which is

```
{{key}}
```

So it should be

```
@MockEndpointsAndSkip("kafka:{{kafka.servers}}?*")
```

See the documentation at: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Camel cannot use `${key}` as that clashes with Spring: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html

Comment: That did it. Thank you. However, I am having other issues running my tests with mocking endpoints.

Comment: Okay then mark this as answered and create a new question for your new problem. Don't just edit the original question

Comment: Thanx Claus, I posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241206/camel-unit-testing-with-mockendpointsandskip