# Camel unit testing with MockEndPointsandSkip

Tags: apache-camel

Am a Camel newbie and am trying out some code to understand how the MockEndpoints functionality works, but it is not working. Here are my Camel routes that I want to unit test using MockEndpoints. The property values are defined in the application.properties file.

```
from("kafka:{{kafka.servers}}?topic={{kafka.consumer.topic}}&groupId={{kafka.consumer.groupId}}")
    .to("direct:notify");

from("direct:notify")
    .log("direct:notfy");
```

Here is my Test code which is failing the assertion of receiving 1 Exchange. It appears that the Producer is never sending the message to my Kafka Mockendpoint:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@MockEndpointsAndSkip("kafka:{{kafka.servers}}?*|direct:notify")
public class NotificationApplicationTests {     

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext context;

    @Value("${kafka.servers}")
    private String kafkaServers;

    @EndpointInject(uri="mock:kafka:{{kafka.servers}}")
    private MockEndpoint mockKafka;

    @EndpointInject(uri="mock:direct:notify")
    private MockEndpoint mockDirect;

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate notiProducer;

    @Test
    public void testMockEndpoints() throws Exception{                                       

        mockDirect.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
        mockDirect.whenAnyExchangeReceived( (Exchange exchange) -> {
            //NEVER GETS HERE!!
            log.info("MOCK DIRECT exchange received");          
        });     

        String payload = "{'email': 'test@gmail.com', 'data': 'ABC1234'}";

        notiProducer.sendBody(mockKafka, payload);

        mockDirect.assertIsSatisfied();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mock endpoint is wrong if you expect it to be a regular expression.

```
@MockEndpointsAndSkip("kafka:{{kafka.servers}}?*|direct:notify")
```

Take care about using `*` in a regular expression. As its not a wildcard, you typically would need to use `.*` to match 0..n characters. Look at bit more on regular expression and maybe use a regular expression tester which you can find online or install as plugin in your Java editor.

Also if you want to replace the route starting with kafka, then you need to do something else as `@MockEndpointsAndSkip` is not for the start. But for sending. See about `replaceFrom` in the advice-with testing section: http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html.

And my book Camel in Action 2nd edition has a lot more documentation in the entire testing chapter: https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition if you are looking for great Camel documentation.

Comment: Thank u so much. It worked after your suggested changes. One question with the 2 routes I have listed above, when I mock the "direct:notify" endpoint and I receive the exchange from my first route (on mock:direct:notify) , the second route does not kick in... why is that?. I would have expected the log "direct:notify", but the second route is never kicked in.

Comment: Because you use ..AndSkip it skips sends to that endpoint. Use the one without AndSkip to also send.

Comment: My understanding was that MockEndpointAndSkip will add the "mock:direct:notify" endpoint and will skip sending the the exchange to the original endpoint "direct:notify", but will send the exchange to "mock:direct:notify" instead. So my second route, which starts with "direct:notify" would also have the "mock:direct:notify" added and I would have assumed the the exchange received at this mocked endpoint from my first route would have been sent to the mocked endpoint in the second route?